# Color wheel in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, circles, applications, angle

Is it possible to arrange the colors of the color wheel on the unit circle in the complex plane such that mixing any two colors results in the color corresponding to the product of the two corresponding points on the complex plane?

Comment: "Mixing two colours" isn't as well-defined as you seem to think. How does your colour-mixing work, exactly?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that if I specified additive or subtractive color mixing, that would be well defined? If so, then my question would be "is it possible for either type of color mixing?"

Comment: The number 1 is the multiplicative identity. What color would you assign to it because mixing it with any other color would leave the color unchanged?

Comment: @themexicanarabesque - Perhaps you could edit your question and ask it in a different manner. As it is written I wonder if this is related to a potential answer: [Representing complex numbers with color](https://userpages.umbc.edu/~squire/images/complex_color.png).

Comment: @Arthur Why not?

Comment: @EtackSxchange Just to take a very simple and immediate example: With paint, mixing yellow and blue gives green. On a television/computer screen, they make yellow by mixing red and green, and adding blue to that gives white. These two colour mixing systems are miles apart.

Comment: @Arthur Oh, I see. Thanks